# What is inaccurate about ProcessingJS image processing?

Tags: processing

The code for the [Convolution example](http://processing.org/learning/topics/convolution.html) says:

> "This example is currently not accurate in JavaScript mode"

What is inaccurate about Javascript mode?  I'd like to do some ProcessingJS image processing, but this warning is worrisome.  What exactly is the source of the inaccuracy?  Are there workarounds?

Comment: I didn't find anything searching the [Processing Forum](http://forum.processing.org/), so you may want to ask there. If you get an answer, feel free to add it as the answer here.

Answer (score 1):

Processing 2.0 has a different API from Processing 1.5.x -- Processing.js 1.4.1 has not fully implemented that API yet, so examples written specifically for Processing 2.0 may not be 100% compatible (yet) with Processing.js

EDIT: to answer the actual question, the only thing that's wrong is that the Processing sketch assumes "  int offset = matrixsize / 2;" is an int. There are no ints in JavaScript, everything is floating point, so to force it to be integer, the line should be "  int offset = int(matrixsize / 2);" and presto. Works exactly as intended.